# Calling a PHP script from objective C code in an iPad

Tags: php, objective-c

I am writing a program for the iPad, in objective C, and I need to call a PHP script which resides on a server. The script should then return a string. Is there a way of doing this from within Objective C?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html)/[NSURLRequest](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSURLRequest). [Here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/cocoa-application-driven-by-http-data.html) you will find a tutorial.

Alternatively, you could use the [ASIHTTPRequest framework](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/), which will make things a little easier, IMO.

Comment: Sad as I am to say it ASIHTTPRequest is dying... The authors recommend [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) though which looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are running the script on the server, so you can get data with NSConnection, NSData and so on.

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"your url"]];
```

Then use data that you got as you like.

Comment: That's the fast solution but also the one that will cause trouble: `dataWithContentsOfURL:` blocks until the data is received or it timed out. You don't want to do that on the main thread as the UI is blocked during that time. Asynchronous `NSURLConnection` is usually the best solution.

Comment: That's true, I forgot to write that it should be called on another thread